# Store in hard disk a CvSVM object

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I have create a SVM detector for faces in opencv. I want to separate the process of train and predict. Thus, I want to find a way to store in my hard disk CvSVM SVM object in order to access it whenever I want without train again a new model. In this way, I could use predict  method  by just loading SVM object from hard disk. This is pretty straight forward in Matlab, but how can I succeed it in opencv c++?

Using load and save functions in order to load and save SVM model it leads to munmap_chunk()::invalid pointer message(glibc detected) message.

```
    CvSVM SVM =  detect.SVMtrain("dbpath/");
    SVM.save("svmTrain.xml", 0);

    cout <<"Detection system in progress progress...\n";
    string pathFile = databasePath+ imageFilename;
    vector<float> confidence;
    detections = detect.detection(pathFile);
    CvSVM SVM;
    SVM.load("svmTrain.xml",0);
    confidence =  detect.SVMpredict(detections.at(0), SVM);
    //cout << "confidence is: " << confidence.at(0) << endl;
```

When I ran the above code I received the above message. The problem stands in svmpredict function. And SVMpredict function:

```
vector<float> Detection::SVMpredict(Mat image, CvSVM SVM){


vector<float> res;

//Mat image = imread(fileName,0); //Read as a gray image
//cvtColor(sampleMat, sampleMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
image = eigenfacesExtraction(image);
image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC1); // <-- Convert to CV_32F for matrix mult

float response = SVM.predict(image); res.push_back(response);
float val = SVM.predict(image,true); res.push_back(val);
cout << "svm result: "<< response <<" val: "<< val << endl;

return res;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward too. It's a `CvStatModel`, so it comes with `save` and `load` methods.

Comment: So saving and loading it could like this SVM.load(".. .xml");//save

Comment: That's the idea, yes. Or .yaml IIRC.

Comment: When I am using load after the svmpredict calculation I am getting a glibc detected mun_map_chunk() invalid pointer:

Comment: I'm going to assumt you mean "use predict **after** load" - that sounds like an OpenCV bug. Of course, if you try to make a prediction with an uninitialized model, that would of course be a bug on your side.

Comment: I am getting the desired resul, I mean svmpredict works i see the result with cout but afterwards I am getting the message.